# Can't figure out why regex group is not working in str_match

Tags: r, regex, regex-group

I have the following code with a regex

```
CHARACTER <- ^([A-Z0-9 .])+(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$
str_match("WILL (V.O.)",CHARACTER)[1,2]
```

I thought this should match the value of "WILL " but it is returning blank.
I tried the RegEx in a different language and the group is coming back blank in that instance also.

What do I have to add to this regex to pull back just the value "WILL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You formed a repeated capturing group by placing `+` outside a group. Put it back:

```
CHARACTER <- "^([A-Z0-9 .]+)(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$"
                          ^
```

Note you may trim `Will` if you use a lazy match with `\s*` after the group:

```
CHARACTER <- "^([A-Z0-9\\s.]+?)\\s*(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbBqsS/2).

```
> library(stringr)
> CHARACTER <- "^([A-Z0-9\\s.]+?)\\s*(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$"
> str_match("WILL (V.O.)",CHARACTER)[1,2]
[1] "WILL"
```

Alternatively, you may just *extract* `Will` with

```
> str_extract("WILL (V.O.)", "^.*?(?=\\s*(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$)")
[1] "WILL"
```

Or the same with base R:

```
> regmatches(x, regexpr("^.*?(?=\\s*(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$)", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "WILL"
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of a string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\\s*(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?$)` - makes sure that, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\\(V\\.O\\.\\))?` - an optional `(V.O.)` substring
  - `(?:\\(O\\.S\\.\\))?` - an optional `(O.S.)` substring
  - `(?:\\(CONT'D\\))?` - an optional `(CONT'D)` substring
  - `$` -  end of string.